# Crystal Report Select Only First Row

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Let say I have the following 2 tables:

Table A:

```
CompanyCode
LocationCode
FormNumber
EmployeeNumber
...
```

Table B:

```
CompanyCode
LocationCode
FormNumber
EmployeeNumber
ClaimDate
...
```

Table A and Table B is joined using all the 4 parameters (`CompanyCode,LocationCode,FormNumber,EmployeeNumber`). These 4 parameters will be input for the report.
One row in table A can have multiple rows in table B.

In the Crystal Report, for each record in table A, I want only the row with the earliest ClaimDate in table B.

Using SQL, this can be accomplished using:

```
SELECT        *
FROM          TableA a
INNER JOIN    TableB b ON 
              a.CompanyCode = b.CompanyCode AND
              a.LocationCode = b.LocationCode AND
              a.FormNumber = b.FormNumber AND
              a.EmployeeNumber = b.EmployeeNumber
WHERE         a.CompanyCode = @CompanyCode AND
              a.LocationCode = @LocationCode AND
              a.FormNumber = @FormNumber AND
              a.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber AND
              b.ClaimDate IN
             (SELECT   MIN(b.ClaimDate)
              FROM     TableB b 
              WHERE    b.CompanyCode = @CompanyCode AND
                       b.LocationCode = @LocationCode AND
                       b.FormNumber = @FormNumber AND
                       b.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber )
```

But I'm not so sure how I can do this in Crystal Report. I tried using SQL Expression, but it seems SQL expression cannot pass the report input.

Comment: how the data in report should look like?

Comment: Actually the data displayed does not involve the values. Just the calculation in the backend. There are 2 sections in the report, and it will be surpressed/not based on the field values. So in that query, I will get another field, name it `Amount`, so it will be the `Amount` of the earliest date. Then this `Amount` will be converted to other value, using the currency table. If this amount exceeds some specific value, it will surpress one section and display another. Vice versa.
So I'm thinking the above as the inital step to solve this problem.

Comment: try something like this... place the data in details section and sort according to the decending order and then write `supress` as `if recordnumber=1 then false else true`.. This is just an idea.. not sure whether it will work.. give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create 4 parameters (`CompanyCode`, `LocationCode` , `FormNumber`, `EmployeeNumber`) in your command.

The command's query:

```
SELECT        *
FROM          TableA a
INNER JOIN    TableB b ON 
              a.CompanyCode = b.CompanyCode AND
              a.LocationCode = b.LocationCode AND
              a.FormNumber = b.FormNumber AND
              a.EmployeeNumber = b.EmployeeNumber
WHERE         a.CompanyCode = {?CompanyCode} AND
              a.LocationCode = {?LocationCode} AND
              a.FormNumber = {?FormNumber} AND
              a.EmployeeNumber = {?EmployeeNumber} AND
              b.ClaimDate IN
             (SELECT   MIN(b.ClaimDate)
              FROM     TableB b 
              WHERE    b.CompanyCode = a.CompanyCode AND
                       b.LocationCode = a.LocationCode AND
                       b.FormNumber = a.FormNumber AND
                       b.EmployeeNumber = a.EmployeeNumber )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, group the rows appropriately for the data in table A. Then create a running total field that starts over for each group (make sure the records are sorted by the date). Once you verify that the running total is correct for each detail row, create a group selection formula that shows records where your running total equals 1.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about why I need to make a running total. This might work as well, but I prefer @craig answer as it's very straightforward. Thanks for helping though :)